# Reporting Multiple Values & Sorting

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, reference, lookup

Having a bit of an issue and unsure if it's actually possible to do.
I'm working on a file that I will enter target progression vs actual target reporting the % outcome.

```
PAGE 1
¦NAME ¦TAR 1 %¦TAR 2 %¦TAR 3 %¦TAR 4 %¦OVERALL¦SUB 1¦SUB 2¦SUB 3¦
¦NAME1¦   114%¦   121%¦   100%¦   250%¦   146%¦    2¦    0¦   0%¦
¦NAME2¦    88%¦   100%¦    90%¦    50%¦    82%¦    0¦    1¦   0%¦
¦NAME3¦    82%¦    54%¦    64%¦   100%¦    75%¦    6¦    6¦  15%¦
¦NAME4¦   103%¦    64%¦    56%¦    43%¦    67%¦    4¦    4¦  24%¦
¦NAME5¦    87%¦    63%¦    89%¦     0%¦    60%¦    3¦    2¦  16%¦
```

Now I already have it sorting all rows by the Overall % column so I can quickly see at a glance but I am creating a second page that I need to reference points.

So on the second page I would like to somehow sort and reference different columns for example

```
PAGE 2
TOP TAR 1¦Name of top %¦Top %¦
TOP TAR 2¦Name of top %¦Top %¦
```

Is something like this possible to do?
Essentially I'm creating an Employee of the Month form that automatically works out who has topped what.

I'm willing to drop a paypal donation for whoever can figure this out for me as I've been doing it manually every month and would appreciate the time saved

Comment: I think OP wants to pick out the maximum % from each column and find the corresponding name - although they're all in the first row in this example they could be in another row. I think it is do-able with an array formula (or possibly a separate formula for the name lookup) - will try and post something tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a complicated array formula is necessary for this - I am suggesting a fairly standard Index/Match approach.

First set up the row titles - you can just copy and transpose them from Page 1, or use a formula in A2 of Page 2 like

```
=transpose('Page 1'!B1:E1)
```

The use them in an index/match to get the data in the corresponding column of the main sheet and find its maximum (in C2)

```
=max(index('Page 1'!A:E,0,match(A2,'Page 1'!A$1:E$1,0)))
```

Finally look up the maximum in the main sheet to find the corresponding name:

```
=index('Page 1'!A:A,match(C2,index('Page 1'!A:E,0,match(A2,'Page 1'!A$1:E$1,0)),0))
```

If you think there could be a tie for first place with two or more people getting the same score, you could use a filter to get the different names:

So if the max score is in B8 this time (same formula)

```
=max(index('Page 1'!A:E,0,match(A8,'Page 1'!A$1:E$1,0)))
```

the different names could be spread across the corresponding row using transpose (in C8)

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(filter('Page 1'!A:A,index('Page 1'!A:E,0,match(A8,'Page 1'!A$1:E$1,0))=B8)))
```

I have changed the test data slightly to show these different scenarios

[image]

Results

[image]